# Expo cli -The development server returned error 500 expo splash screen

Tags: react-native, expo

I am new to react native expo cli and followed all the required steps. Now I am creating splash screen from this link: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v46.0.0/sdk/splash-screen/

however I'm stuck in this error while loading the app

[image]

here is **App.js** code

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Entypo from '@expo/vector-icons/Entypo';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

// Keep the splash screen visible while we fetch resources
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      try {
        // Pre-load fonts, make any API calls you need to do here
        await Font.loadAsync(Entypo.font);
        // Artificially delay for two seconds to simulate a slow loading
        // experience. Please remove this if you copy and paste the code!
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {
        // Tell the application to render
        setAppIsReady(true);
      }
    }

    prepare();
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (appIsReady) {
      // This tells the splash screen to hide immediately! If we call this after
      // `setAppIsReady`, then we may see a blank screen while the app is
      // loading its initial state and rendering its first pixels. So instead,
      // we hide the splash screen once we know the root view has already
      // performed layout.
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}
      onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
      <Text>SplashScreen Demo! </Text>
      <Entypo name="rocket" size={30} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you installed package by

```
npx expo install expo-splash-screen
```

then stop server by `ctrl + c` then start server again.